# if/else coding style consequences

Tags: if-statement

I am a novice programmer and was in lecture one evening, we were studying the "if,else" coding section from my professor and I was curious about an aspect of it. What I was curious about was if we have a bunch of nested if,else's in our program, is it just bad coding style to end an if,else with an "else,if" line of code instead of if "x", else "y"? For example,

```
if "x"
else if "y"
else if "z"
end
```

compared to

```
if "x"
else if "y"
else "z"
end
```

It would still run the program without an error, but are there consequences later on other than having bad programming style?

Comment: In the first case you can enter in the Z case. In the second no. If not x and if not y you are sure is Z?

Answer (score 0):

Behind the curtain JS dont really have else if, all it is doing is generating another if statement when parsed.

e.g:

```
if(foo){

} else if (baz){

}
```

becomes

```
if (foo){

} else {
   if (baz){

   }
}
```

So the reason for using another else if in the end instead of else is when you want to control the else statement as-well and not just pass to that case everything else that don't fit in your first condition... (In order to control the else condition and filter it to the necessary items only)

if you do have a really long statement with a lot of else-if conditions you should consider using switch statement instead.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what you are looking to do. The former example makes sure that all IF requirements are met. There would be instances that none of the IFs get hit in this case.

In the latter example however, ELSE "Z" would get hit for sure if all above IFs fail. This would be useful if you are assigning a variable within your IFs - your variable will definitely have a value at the end of the IF statement. If it was as in the first example, the variable will be null and might result in a null error if you try to use it later.

If there are a lot of if-thens, I would checkout the case/switch statement as well, as it is more neater to implement.

Also, remember to comment your code well - especially explaining what all the nested IFs are doing.